# Fantasy novel about kid who finds out the 'evil warlock' is his father?

Tags: story-identification, magic

This book was similar to the whole Star Wars Luke Skywalker/Darth Vader story, except it's a fantasy novel.  I seem to recall that it was more of a 'young adult' level book.

Details I remember:

- Young adult level
- Written on or before the late 80's
- Heavy Norse influence in names, locations, environment
- Main character finds out that the evil scary warlord? warlock? he'd heard about is his father
- Father turns out to be NOT evil in the end
- Possibly written by female author
- Possibly studies magic with a wizard when he finds he can do magic
- Wizard possibly turns out to be a bad guy
- Upon meeting his father (near the end?) he runs off and becomes a hermit for a time (few years?)

Comment: Explanation for the downvote?

Comment: Sounds like Star Wars, except for the Norse names.

Comment: @Jeff - "Darth Vader" is Norse :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After much googling and brain-wracking, I finally found it:

[The Wizard and the Warlord](http://www.fictiondb.com/author/elizabeth-boyer%7Ewizard-and-the-warlord%7E115386%7Eb.htm) by Elizabeth Boyer

> Sigurd grew up with his grandmother, bothered only by the trolls that seemed bent on destroying their settlement. Then she died, leaving him a mysterious box he couldn't open and a confused warning against some dread warlord or wizard--he couldn't be sure of which from her final ravings. Then the grim warlord Halfdane came to abduct him by force into the Realm of the Alfar.
>
> Now he was a virtual prisoner in the hill fort of Halfdane, caught in a bitter war between light and dark elves. And he seemed trapped on the losing side. His only hope was to escape and somehow learn what powerful magic was contained in the box and which everyone seemed bent on stealing from him.
>
> Of course, there were a few walking dead, a cursed sword, and a multitude of savage trolls to be faced. But the strange wizard Jotull was willing--oh, very willing--to help him!

I think the fact that I kept remembering it as warlock hindered my googling...

Answer (score 2):

Check out [The Sword of Truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sword_of_Truth) series by Terry Goodkind. It is not exactly how you described, but close enough for you to perhaps check it out. (The evil father is evil, though).

Comment: I'd say calling Darken Rahl evil is an understatement ;-)

Comment: After reading the other ten books, perhaps not so much. But point taken.

Comment: Nope, not Sword of Truth.  I've read those, and enjoyed them!  The book in question tho, I read as a kid.  Late 80's.  I think, um, what's his name Terry Goodkind? wrote those afterwards, since the last one came out just a couple years ago.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds vaguely like the [Magician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magician_%28novel%29) series, by Raymond Feist. Early 80s, takes place in a land called Midkemia, easy to read at the high school level.